# Tabs, should it be a window or view?

Tags: ios, titanium

When you build a tab application, should each tab be a view or a window?

Many developers say your app should only have one window with many views. Other developers say use windows for each tab.

Which is correct practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule with iOS apps is that you want one UIWindow instance per physical screen. Until iOS added better multiscreen support, and the newer hardware was able to natively support app mirroring, most apps used one window, unless it explicitly supported a second display.

It follows then, that you want one UITabBarController to show instances of UIViewController objects. This rule should hold true regardless of the SDK you're using to write your apps, assuming that titanium maps its classes back to their native Objective-C counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

The window doesn't have many views in a normal app, its simply hosts views while being displayed. I have never heard of using windows in tab views, I have several apps out that use tabbarcontrollers and I always use UIViewController subclasses (or UINavigationController subclasses) with a view in its nib - all works perfectly fine.